# Possible to know if member has cloned source code from git repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am wondering if we can check somewhere that we can see if members of the git repository has cloned the source code?

If yes, can we check how many times they have cloned the source code?

For your information we are using Bitbucket.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the github repository main page and click on Graphs link(on the right hand side of the page, then click on the Traffic tab. It will show you when and how many times your repository has been cloned. It will also tell you how many of the clones where from contributors and how many are unique. I do not believe it will tell you which individual member cloned it though.[image]

Comment: Wow thanks for the reply, unfortunately I am using Bitbucket, not Github. Do you know where we can view that? I can't seem to find it :(

Comment: @jonprasetyo AFAIK, Bitbucket doesn't provide that kind of data.